# spring4.0 websocket issue

Tags: spring, websocket

code partial:

```
@MessageMapping("/string")
@SendTo("topic/test2")
public String hello2(String a) throws Exception{
  System.out.println(a);
  Thread.sleep(2000);
//simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/test2","Send From backend");
  return "This is message 2";
}

<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/app" user-destination-prefix="/user">
<websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/websocket">
  <websocket:sockjs/>
</websocket:stomp-endpoint>
<websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic"/>
```

I send a message use sockJS and stomp.js.

```
var websocket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/todo/websocket');
var client = Stomp.over(websocket);
  client.connect('benjamin','benjamin',function(msg){
  client.send('/app/string',{},'string');
}
```

I recive message on server side but throw a exception:

```
org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized token 'string': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
at [Source: [B@31e018db; line: 1, column: 13]
```

Spring version 4.0.6-RELEASE

I read the code ,find spring has 3 message Converters,
but when spring use

```
MappingJackson2MessageConverter.convertFromInternal
```

covert message throw this exception.should spring catch this exception and try use other coverters covert message? Is it a bug?

How can resolve it,someone can help me?

Comment: spring will inject the raw message Object as an Annotated Method parameter.I can get what I need from the raw message object such as byte[].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got de the question too.
And I solve it by a bad method.

```
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

.......

@Override
public boolean configureMessageConverters(List<MessageConverter> messageConverters) {
    messageConverters.add(new StringMessageConverter());
    messageConverters.add(new ByteArrayMessageConverter());
    return false;
}
}
```

disable JsonConvertor